# Change the numbering on an ordered list?

Tags: javascript, html, css

You can change the number at which an ordered list starts like this:

```
<ol start="3">
    <li>item three</li>
    <li>item four</li>
</ol>
```

...but is there a way to make list items have arbitrary numbers, not just consecutive numbering?

```
<ol>
    <li>item two</li>
    <li>item six</li>
    <li>item nine</li>
</ol>
```

The only way I can see to do it now is to wrap each `<li>` in its own `<ol>` which obviously isn't ideal. HTML, Javascript and CSS solutions are welcome.

*ps: though the item numbers are arbitrary, they are still ordered, so don't be fretting about the semantics*

Comment: I've posted a 'hacky' javascript solution below, but, I am curious, why do you want to do something like this?

Comment: For crossword clues - since the Down and Across words are separated into different lists, the numbers aren't sequential.

Comment: So what did you do in the end?

Comment: Wrapped each li in its own ol. Like I said, it's not ideal, but it works. The value attribute would have been good, but my page is XHTML strict. :(

Comment: Check out my revised answer, just in case... be interested to know what you think.

Answer (score 18):

In [HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/lists.html) there is a deprecated `value` attribute on `<li>` :

```
<ol>
<li value="30"> makes this list item number 30.
<li value="40"> makes this list item number 40.
<li> makes this list item number 41.
</ol>
```

The non-deprecated (CSS) answer is (as so often) more elegant but less... direct :) The [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html) is somewhat dry; googling turns up more immediately usable stuff such as [this](http://papayapariah.com/?action=view&url=the-proper-way-to-number-an-ordered-list-ol) :

> Just like continuing the numbering
>   from the previous list you’ll need to
>   set the CSS property for incrementing
>   the proper counter. But to make it
>   start incrementing from a different
>   starting point you can pass an
>   optional second parameter in
>   counter-reset property of a number. So
>   starting from 5 would look something
>   like this in your CSS:
>
> ```
> ol.continue {
>   counter-reset: chapter 4;     /* Resets counter to 4. */
> }
> ```
>
> Since the counter will always be reset
>   before it is incremented, to start our
>   list with the number 5 we will have to
>   set the counter to 4.

Comment: so with that CSS option, that would require non-sequential items to be wrapped in their own OL?

Comment: The example isn't entirely relevant. You can change the rule to `ol li.myclass` for your purposes.

Comment: HTML5 actually allows @value again, because it is, actually, not a presentational attribute.

Answer (score 13):

There's the `value` attribute on `li`, although that's deprecated:

```
<ol>
    <li value="2">item two</li>
    <li value="6">item six</li>
    <li value="9">item nine</li>
</ol>
```

The [w3schools page for `<li.@value>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_li_value.asp) says:

> The value attribute of the li element
>   was deprecated in HTML 4.01, and is
>   not supported in XHTML 1.0 Strict DTD.
>
> **Note:** At the moment, there is no CSS
>   alternative for the value attribute.

(Despite saying "use styles" for the deprecation warning on the main [`<li>`](http://w3schools.com/tags/tag_li.asp) page.)

The [HTML 5 editor's draft reference for `li`](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/#the-li-element) suggests it's still valid there...

Comment: Yes, `value` is still there, and it's also no longer deprecated in HTML5.

Answer (score 6):

Looking at all these answers is making me feel a bit icky. Do you really really want to use LIs for this? If it means creating 'dummy' lis, or javascript, or custom CSS classes, I would start looking at other possibilities. The point of an LI (to my mind) is NOT managing the numbering yourself. If you have to manage the numbers yourself, then you're only using LI to manage the style - how about creating your own style and just sticking your numbers in a <span> or something?

Comment: @nickf, sorry I changed my answer. I believe your comment is still valid, but you might not!

Comment: thanks for taking the extra time on this question. You make a good point - the situation has diverged somewhat from the original semantic purpose of using a list. The reason I particularly want to use an OL though, is for the ease of styling. All the margins are set up and working. Fudging things like list-style-position using divs isn't my idea of fun.

Answer (score 4):

Deprecated HTML way

```
<ol>
   <li>List item 1</li>
   <li VALUE=5 TYPE="A">List item E</li>
   <li>List item 3</li>
</ol>
```

[CSS way](http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=137453)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">

<style type="text/css">
ol { 
    counter-reset:item; 
 }
li {
    display:block; 
 }
li:before { 
    content:counter(item) '. '; 
    counter-increment:item; 
 }
#new_number {
    counter-reset:item 24;
 }
</style>

<!--[if IE]>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function() {
   document.getElementById('new_number').value='25';
 }
</script>
<![endif]-->

</head>
<body>

<ol>
  <li id="new_number">list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
  <li>list item</li>
</ol>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note: `value` attribute was deprecated in HTML4, but reintroduced in HTML5.

Answer (score 3):

For example -

```
<ol id="reverse_numbering">
    <li>foo</li>
    <li>bar</li>
    <li>baz</li>
</ol>
```

This is something you can do -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var reverse = $('reverse_numbering');
    reverse.style.listStyle='none';
    var li = reverse.getElementsByTagName('li');
    for(var i=0; i<li.length; i++) {
        li[i].insertBefore(document.createTextNode(li.length-i+'. '), li[i].firstChild);
    }
</script>
```

Reference: [HTML Help Forums](http://forums.htmlhelp.com/lofiversion/index.php/t1038.html).

Answer (score 1):

It's actually even easier than you think. What you're doing is basically "pausing" a list so you can insert something. When you do this in text you use the `&lt;div&gt;` tag. (Bells ringning now?")

CSS

```
...<br />

/* This style removes the indentation that &lt;ol&gt; creates. In my document it was 30pt */<br />
.pauselist {margin-left:-30pt;}
<br />
<br />
XHTML<br />
...<br />
&lt;p&gt;Text&lt;/p&gt;<br />
&lt;p&gt;Text&lt;/p&gt;<br />
&lt;ol&gt;<br />
  &lt;li&gt;Item 1&lt;/li&gt;<br />
  &lt;li&gt;Item 2<br />
    &lt;div class="pauselist"&gt;<br />
&lt;p&gt;Text&lt;/p&gt;<br />
&lt;p&gt;Text&lt;/p&gt;<br />
&lt;p&gt;Text&lt;/p&gt;<br />
&lt;!-- Okay now let's continue with the list --&gt;<br /> 
    &lt;/div&gt;<br />
  &lt;/li&gt;<br />
  &lt;li&gt;Item 3&lt;/li&gt;<br />
  &lt;li&gt;Item 4&lt;/li&gt;<br />
&lt;/ol&gt;<br />
&lt;p&gt;Text&lt;/p&gt;<br />
&lt;p&gt;Text&lt;/p&gt;<br />
<br />
<pre>
```

------ Results ---------
Text
Text

1. Item 1
2. Item 2

Text
Text
Text

1. Item 3
2. Item 4

Text
Text

Comment: That's more than a bit hacky, and doesn't even solve the problem (where the list might go like this: `Item 2, Item 4, Item 9`)

Answer (score 0):

I think this problem starts from semantics (wich, you know, is one of the pillars of creating standard-based pages): You want to use an **ordered** list to represent an *unordered* one.

My suggestions:

1) Use a ul and add images with numbers based on classes (this can be done programatically and you only have to generate the number images once, plus it gives you styling options)

2) Use a definition list. I know its stretching semantics a little bit but if the "term" (dt) is "Horizontal" and the definitions (dd) are the crossword's options I think it becomes semantic. Using this you can add the numbers you want and style them using whichever tag you like.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I disagree that the list is unordered. It's in ascending order, and the fifth item in the list is the fifth horizontal or vertical word in the puzzle. It's just that the number of each word isn't consecutive.

Comment: Mmmh I hadn't understood that originally so I stand corrected :) I kept thinking about the issue and I think going with a <dl> would be the most "degradable". It would be semantically sound and it would show the content would be accesible and understandable to any user agent or browser (javascript capable or not)... the downside is if the list is generated manually.