# Splitting list items into vertical columns

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm a little rusty on my UL/LI syntax and I was wondering how you make a list wrap. For example make:

1
2
3
4
5
6

Look like:

1  4
2  5
3  6

Right now I have a header, content, and footer (all with a height set to a certain %) I want the list to wrap once it reaches the footer, or the bottom of the content %.

So what I want as a final product is a content div to dynamically change size based on what can fit in the screen. If I have 12 items and the screen can fit 2 columns then it will be 2 columns with 6 rows, if the screen can fit 4 columns then it will be 4 columns with 3 rows, ect.

Comment: experiment with `overflow` and `white-space` properties

Comment: 0sh's suggestion will only work if you want it horizontally. Consider experimenting with `column-count` instead for vertical.

Comment: As far as I know CSS alone doesn't have any fully supported way to wrap columns

Comment: I need more info on the context before I can help. Why would you be setting your height that way? Are you making a webpage? When and why does the list "reach" the footer? etc

Comment: ExplosionPills - you can just float things and use @media rules to make all sorts of columns.

Comment: @sheriffderek: How would you make two columns without `-webkit`-prefixed CSS properties?

Comment: @Blender AH - I see it now, it's not just a grid... silly me. yeah. I guess I just always plan out my projects so that I don't count on "columns" --- soon enough there will be full support. For now you could use columns and just have a decent graceful degradation -

Comment: If you are generating your page dynamically, it will be much easier to achieve it server side and use css to alter numbering: http://stackoverflow.com/a/994807/486780

Comment: You could fake it with some clever floating and media queries... but it wouldn't be very modular or reusable. Maybe first-of-child(even) or something and some negative margins... let me see...

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't specific, maybe my edit will help (last paragraph) this will be a mobile site so I want it to look the same (minus the number of columns and rows) based on the screen size. i.e. tablets vs phones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, this is stupid... but it does work... however, it only works in certain cases and involves a ton of *silly* numbers. Definitely not modular. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/WCup6/) (do I need to mention you'll need to resize your browser?)

HTML

```
<ul>
    <li>01</li>
    <li>02</li>
    <li>03</li>
    <li>04</li>
    <li>05</li>
    <li>06</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
/* apply a natural box layout model to all elements */
* { -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0; margin: 0;
    width: 4em;
    border: 1px solid orange;
    overflow: hidden; /* in place of clearing float */
}

ul li {
    position: relative; /* for the negative top distance to work */
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em;
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}

ul li:nth-of-type(n+4) {
    float: right;
    clear: none;
    top: -6em;    
}


@media (min-width: 30em) {

    ul {
        width: auto;
        float: left;
    }

    ul li {
        float: left;
        clear: none;
        border: 1px solid green;
    }

    ul li:nth-of-type(n+4) {
       float: left;
       top: 0;
    }

} /* =========== end === */
```

I'm betting there is a nice jQuery something for this... If your table isn't being dynamically populated with different amounts of information - you could do something like this cosmetically or use some absolute positioning - columns is probably the way to go though. Good luck...

Answer (score 2):

you may use CSS column and start basicly styling your ul like this:

```
ul {column-count:2;
/* other styles*/
   }
```

Comment: I don't want a specific set number of columns or rows. (See edit, last paragraph) Sorry if I wasn't specific

Comment: You can place this column declaration in different media query rules and change the number based on window size.

Comment: you could also set a width instead of numbers like  "column-width:8em;"   Numbers of column will adjust within width avalaible. but no option to set a  specific height size , nor min, nor max.